# When I read EXAMPLE 2 on p.131 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres, I felt strange. So I modified the solution as follows.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, improper-integrals

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

The following example is EXAMPLE 2 on p.131.

[image]

When I read this example, I felt strange:

(1) The author wrote that $f$ is bounded on $A$. But the author proved that $f$ is bounded on $U_n\subset A$.

(2) We can apply the Fubini theorem to $f$ on a closed rectangle $Q$. But $U_N$ is an open rectangle.

So, I modified the solution of EXAMPLE 2 as follows:

> Let $U_N:=(1,N)\times (1,N)$ for $N=2,3,\dots$.
> $\overline{U_N}$ is a closed rectangle.
> $f$ is a continuous function on $\overline{U_N}.$
> So, $\int_{\overline{U_N}} f$ exists.
> By Theorem 13.6 above, $\int_{U_N} f$ exists and $\int_{U_N} f=\int_{\overline{U_N}} f.$
> By the Fubini theorem, $\int_{\overline{U_N}} f=\int_{x=1}^{x=N} \int_{y=1}^{y=N} 1/x^2y^2=((N-1)/N)^2.$
> By Theorem 15.6 above, we conclude that $\int_A f=1.$

Is this solution better?

Comment: Not really. First, it is totally elementary that $f$ is bounded on $A$. His comments that $f$ is bounded on $U_N$ were not at all meant to justify that assertion. Second, why is he bothering to write the integral over a non-closed rectangle? Because $A$ does not contain $\bar U_N$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Professor Shifrin, Thank you very much for your answer!